# Keep getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when recording with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I started getting this error with the version 3.1 and I just installed 3.2, it seems like I'm still getting the same error over and over again with the newest version too.

I'm running the HTTPs(s) Test Script Recorder and after I login to the page, it records the steps properly up to that point and then it stops recording and I keep getting the same error, Array index out of bound exception, wherever I click on the website that I'm recording. Any idea?

```
        2017-08-21 12:05:52,719 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :root_ca:
    2017-08-21 12:05:52,719 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.ProxyControl: Valid alias found for :intermediate_ca:
    2017-08-21 12:05:52,719 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Creating Daemon Socket on port: 8080
    2017-08-21 12:05:52,719 INFO o.a.j.p.h.p.Daemon: Test Script Recorder up and running!
    2017-08-21 12:06:14,386 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:15,760 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:15,776 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:15,807 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:15,823 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:16,493 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:16,993 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:17,056 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:18,187 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    2017-08-21 12:06:18,312 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.createAuthorization(ProxyControl.java:692) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:624) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:3.2 r1790748]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the error as text, not as picture.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug which was reported under the below Id and fixed in JMeter 3.3 (upcoming as of August 2017) :

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61456

It was fixed by avoiding the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, still it would be nice from you to test nightly :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

And provide

- jmeter.log full stacktrace and possibly the whold file
- the HTTP request content that triggers the error, particularly the headers

With those elements, you could get a more accurate answer.

Comment: how do you know JMeter 3.3 release date?

Comment: there is no release date, just indications based on mailing list discussion and knowing we contribute to it.